# We want to bring the button to the center of the image

Tags: html, css

button top of the image and **vertical** and **horizontal** center
I using *margin* but not properly work

> without using margin

```html
   <html>
        <head>
         <style type="text/css">
          .box-cover{
            width:100%;
            height:80vh;
          }
          button{
           padding:20px 30px;
           background-color:red;
           border:none;
           color:white;
           border-radius:5em;
          }
        </style>
       </head>
       <body>
        <div class="box">
         <img class="box-cover" src="https://media.sproutsocial.com/uploads/2017/02/10x-featured-social-media-image-size.png">
         <button>Click ME</button>
        </div> 
       </body>
      </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean this result?

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
}
.box-cover{
  width:100%;
  height:80vh;
}
button{
  padding:20px 30px;
  background-color:red;
  border:none;
  color:white;
  border-radius:5em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img class="box-cover" src="https://media.sproutsocial.com/uploads/2017/02/10x-featured-social-media-image-size.png">
  <button>Click ME</button>
</div>
```

Comment: If the size of the image is small or large, the button will move to one side or the other.

Comment: Do you mean the case button width is bigger than image width?

Comment: @Coozera, please check the answer you accepted carefully. That has some issue.

Comment: sorry i couldn't check properly

Answer (score 0):

If I mean and understand:

```
    .box {
        text-align: center;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you set a width on your container class `box` you can use `text-align: center;` to center the button.

```css
.box-cover{
  width: 100%;
  height:80vh;
}
button {
  padding:20px 30px;
  background-color:red;
  border:none;
  color:white;
  border-radius:5em;
  text-align: center;
  
}
.box {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="box">
    <img class="box-cover" src="https://media.sproutsocial.com/uploads/2017/02/10x-featured-social-media-image-size.png">
    <button>Click ME</button>
  </div>
</body>
```